# vs 2008 express: registration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

Did any one have luck recently register Visual studio 2008 express C# product? Look like, I would have to reformat my computer and install every thing all over again. I un-installed it and installed VS2008 express again but it will not start because it demands registration. When I click the register button, the website launches and hour glass spins forever. It appears that MS Express edition registration site may not be working.

Please help..

Comment: I finally was able to register. First of all use latest version of IE. Then follow the directions in this thread. I was finally able to register.

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/GettingReadyforWindows7/thread/3889882a-4f35-49a4-b975-43177e335d5c

Comment: Link in comment is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using google chrome as your registration browser... Try using IE and you should be able to do it. (you can paste the URL and it works)

Answer (score 12):

If you delete the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/VCExpress/9.0/Registration` you will no longer be asked to register.

Open regedit, navigate using above folder, then remove the entire 'Registration' folder.

Comment: Further, to prevent it from recreating the registration key at startup, do what I did in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30540370/2844375

Comment: Golden answer. Up one !

Comment: Thank you very much, God bless you

Answer (score 0):

You can do an offline install from this link.  You can simply mount the ISO with a virtual CD program instead of burning one:
http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/offline.aspx

Comment: Installation in not an issue. Even after I re-install, when I would start the VS2008 express C#, the applicaiton would prompt me to register or Exit. If I try to register, the browser will not respond. Its forcing me to reformat my computer.

Comment: From what I read, the offline install does not require registration.