# How do I get the serial key for Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I am Visual Studio 2010 Professional user. But for a reason I need Visual Web Developer 2008 Express edition.

I downloaded this, but I need the serial key to activate the product, otherwise it will expire in 30 days.

When I go [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsreg/default.aspx?rel=vs2008&lcid=1033&h=d9eac95a73d80105&c=&pid=91911-152-0000077-60782&bn=030729.01), I got this error:

> "Thank you for your interest in registering Visual Studio. We are
> currently experiencing issues with the registration process. We are
> working on this and will have it fixed as soon as possible. Please try
> to register your product again at a later time. We apologize for the
> inconvenience."

I tried for a long time, but I got the same error every time. Is there any other way to get the serial key?

Answer (score 51):

I have an improvement on the [answer @DewiMorgan gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572760/3195477) for VS 2008 express. I have since confirmed it also works on VS 2005 express.

It lets you run the software without it EVER requiring registration, and also makes it so you don't have to manually delete the key every 30 days. It does this by preventing the key from ever being written.

(Deleting the correct key can also let you avoid registering VS 2015 "Community Edition," but using permissions to prevent the key being written will make the IDE crash, so I haven't found a great solution for it yet.)

The directions assume Visual C# Express 2008, but this works on all the other visual studio express apps I can find.

1. Open regedit, head to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VCSExpress\9.0\Registration`.
2. Delete the value `Params`.
   [image: picture of me deleting the value 'Params' in the registry.]
3. Right click on the key 'Registration' in the tree, and click `permissions`.
4. Click `Advanced...`
5. Go to the `permissions` tab, and uncheck the box labeled `Inherit from parent the permission entries that apply to child objects. Include these with entries explicitly defined here.`
   [image: me unchecking the box]
6. In the dialog that opens, click `copy`.
   [image: the security dialog that pops up]
   Note that in Windows 7 (and 8/8.1, I think), it appears the `copy` button was renamed to `add`, as in `add inherited permissions as explicit permissions`.
   In Windows 10, it appears things changed again. @ravuya says that you might have to manually re-create some of the permissions, as the registry editor no longer offers this exact functionality directly. I don't use Windows very much anymore, so I'll defer to them:

> On Win10, there is a button called "Disable Inheritance" that does the same thing as the checkbox mentioned in step 5. It is necessary to create new permissions just for `Registration`, instead of inheriting those permissions from an upstream registry key.
> 7. Hit `OK` in the 'Advanced' window.
> 8. Back in the first permissions window, click your user, and uncheck `Full Control`.
> [image: Me unchecking 'full control']

9. Do the same thing for the `Administrators` group.
   [image: Me unchecking 'full control' for the Administrators group]
10. Hit `OK` or `Apply`.
    Congratulations, you will never again be plagued by the registration nag, and just like WinRAR, your trial will never expire.

You may have to do the same thing for other (non-Visual C#) programs, like Visual Basic express or Visual C++ express.

It has been reported by @IronManMark20 in the comments that simply deleting the registry key works and that Visual Studio does not attempt to re-create the key. I am not sure if I believe this because when I installed VS on a clean windows installation, the key was not created until I ran VS at least once. But for what it's worth, that may be an option as well.

Comment: The registration link for Visual C# 2008 Express doesn't work anymore, so this seeems to be the only solution. I hate M$ policy so much.

Comment: @JanTuroň agreed. it really sucks

Comment: @vojta Glad to help :D

Comment: In Windows 10, I just had to delete the key. No permissions editing needed.

Comment: for VS2005? i bet it'll create the key on next run and you'll get the nag in another 30 days, but if you say so I have no choice but to take your word for it - I refuse to upgrade to 10 until I can disable telemetry.

Comment: @IronManMark20 forgot to reply directly to you so you got the notification. I'm interested. You mean you deleted  the registration key, and VS didn't bother re-creating the key? It did for me when I tried, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Wyatt8740, I deleted the registry key, and it worked. IDK why.

Comment: @IronManMArk20 yes, it will work if you just delete it: but did it work for MORE THAN 30 DAYS? That's the important part.

Comment: @DewiMorgan, yes it did. :D

Comment: @IronManMark Thanks for the clarification! Tempting to upgrade to Win10 to test this.

Comment: @DavidHerrero Glad to hear! It's sad Microsoft makes us resort to this now.

Comment: On Win10, there is a button called "Disable Inheritance" that does the same thing as the checkbox mentioned in step 5. It is necessary to create new permissions just for Registration, instead of inherit those permissions from an upstream registry key. Works great.

Comment: @ravuya good to know. I still use 7 when I have to use windows and I typically am not in Windows at all, so I wasn't aware of this. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me for Visual C++ 2010 Express. Although the registry key is not recreated once the permissions have been changed, it still prompts to register every time it's started, with the only other option being "Close".

Comment: @CJDennis hm. I don't really use Windows much anymore (linux now). My guess is your trial had already expired when you did this, or something.

Comment: really? do we have to?

Answer (score 11):

The question is about VS 2008 Express.

Microsoft's web page for registering Visual Studio 2008 Express has been dead (404) for some time, so registering it is not possible.

Instead, as a workaround, you can temporarily remove the requirement to register VS2008Exp by deleting (or renaming) the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/VCExpress/9.0/Registration
```

To ensure that this is working beforehand, click Help -> register product within VS2008.

You should see text like

> "You have not yet registered your copy of Visual C++ 2008 Express
> Edition. This product will run for **10** more days before you will be
> required to register it."

Close the application, delete that key, reopen, click help->register product.

The text should now say

> "You have not yet registered your copy of Visual C++ 2008 Express
> Edition. This product will run for **30** more days before you will be
> required to register it."

So you have two options - delete that key manually every 30 days, or run it from a batch file that also contains a line like:

```
reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VCExpress\9.0\Registration /f
```

[Edit: User @i486 confirms on testing that this workaround works even after the expiration period has expired]

[Edit2: User @Wyatt8740 has [a much more elegant way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540370/3195477) to prevent the value from reappearing.]

Comment: That depends on whether it sets a flag somewhere else to say "registration timed out". Test it? Set your system clock a couple months in the future?

You may want to try this in a virtual machine :)

Comment: I tested it on a system with VCS 2008. The 30 day period was expired. But after deleting the key, it works :) I think about a solution with Permissions - if I change them and VCS is not able to re-create the key...

Answer (score 1):

Visual C# Express 2005 ISO File does not require registration

Answer (score -1):

I believe that if you download the offline ISO image file, and use that to install Visual Studio Express, you won't have to register.

Go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#Visual_Studio_2008_Express_Downloads) and find the link that says "All - Offline Install ISO image file". Click on it to expand it, select your language, and then click "Download".

Otherwise, it's possible that online registration is simply down for a while, as the error message indicates. You have 30 days before it expires, so give it a few days before starting to panic.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the offline ISO. It is now prompting me to enter a registration key. :( I should also mention, though, that I'm using 2010 Express.