# VB 2008 Express Registration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have VC++, VC# and VB Express 2008 installed on my computer. I have registered VC# and VC++ products but when I try to register VB Express 2008, there is no registration box appear. In fact, when I click Help -> Register Product, it opens a MS Registration web page in the browser instead of opening the registration box, asks me to enter my EMail info and after a while web page says thanks to mine instead of registration number as if I have already register the product. I installed VC++ and VC# by the web installer and installed VB from the DVD-ISO image of VS Express 2008 SP1.

Any suggestion would be worth!

Comment: Usually i think when you click Help->Register product it will register the whole express edition. There is no need to register separately.

Answer (score 0):

VB Express is a free edition and does not provide a registration number or anything like that. It's just stored online so they have a record that someone else is using their software.

Comment: Thanks but when I installed VC++ Express 2008 sp1 and VC# Express 2008 sp1, I gained a registration key from the website and entered in the registration box that appears by clicking help -> Register Product option, for the free registration of the products. Now what about it?

Comment: Maybe VB Express doesn't provide a registration key, I'm not entirely sure as I use VS Pro.

Comment: Thanks Mr Dark Slipstream! I am still waiting for a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to register a while back. I posted complete instructions in this answer: [How do I get the serial key for Visual Studio Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422745/how-do-i-get-the-serial-key-for-visual-studio-express/30540370#30540370)

Just replace `VCSexpress` with `VBexpress` while navigating the registry.