# Cannot register Visual C++ 2008 Express edition

Tags: visual-c++

Could anyone please help me to register the VC++ 2008 Express edition?

I went to Help - Register. And then, it said I should hit the "Register now" link, which points to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=92705&lcid=1033&h=d47cc4cc7e4f0893&c=&pid=91909-152-0000052-60863&bn=030729.01

However, when I go to that page it says “We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.”

Could anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor support question that can only be answered by that vendor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the serial key for Visual Studio Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422745/how-do-i-get-the-serial-key-for-visual-studio-express)